# Adding ints before each item(strings) in list

Tags: python, list

If I have a list in Python like:

```
Notes = ["F5","G5","B5"]
```

Then how would I go about adding a growing number before each of the items?
So the output would look something like this:

```
magic

print(newlist)

#2, F5, 4, G5, 6, B5
```

For example, what I have tried is:

```
midi = ["F5","G5","C5"]
for m in midi:

    output = (note.Note(m))

    n1 = note.Note('G', type='half')
    st4 = stream.Stream()
    st4.append(n1)

    for n in output:
        p += 2

        print( p, output)

    st4.insert(output)
    print(st4)
```

This gives me the error:

> *Object is not iterable*.

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: I have tried append and using a for loop to add it in however it does not seem to work. Ideally, I would like to convert the old list into the new one. So my input is the old list then my new list would have an increasing number by 2. I can't figure out how to convert the old list into the new one and haven't found anything online that can help. yet.

Comment: So give a [mre].

Comment: I don't understand the logic of how your result comes from the input at all. It would help if you gave *precise* outputs, `#2, F5, 4, G5, 6, B5` is totally ambiguous

Comment: the library I am using is music21. So the note.Note() is a function that takes a string. This currently ouputs without the "for in output" as the midi as a function of each item in the list. However I need to then add to that list 2 increasing before each note. If that makes sense

Comment: the code kinda messed up above. but the for loop is below the midi =

Comment: I need this because the first list will always be changing.

Comment: **Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message.**

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using a for loop for `i` from `2` to `2 * (len_of_list + 1)` advancing in steps equal to 2. Then, insert the value `i` at index `i - 2`:

```
notes = ["F5", "G5", "B5"] # notes list
newlist = notes # copy original list

 # for loop starting at 2 and stopping at 7 from 2 to 6 given that step = 2
for i in range(2, 2 * (len(notes) + 1), 2):
    newlist.insert(i - 2, i) # insert value i (2, 4, 6) at index i - 2 (0, 2, 4)

# prints result
print(", ".join(str(value) for value in newlist))
```

**Output:**
2, F5, 4, G5, 6, B5